# common input validation mistakes in flash

Tags: flash, xss, sql-injection

i know the drill to find XSS and injection at sites made with javascript, php, java, mysql...

Basically, I know how to write the bugs, so i know to find them.

Now i'm evaluating a product which the frontend is flash. what are the common mistakes I should be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XSS Vulnerabilities in Common Shockwave Flash Files](http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=ajfxntc4dmsq_14dt57ssdw)